How to apply --speed flag for ffmpeg-kit in React Native (Expo)?
Where do i place speed flag?
Currently my plugins look like this
"plugins": [
      [
        "@config-plugins/ffmpeg-kit-react-native",
        {
          "package": "min-gpl"
        }
      ]
    ],

I use expo sdk 51.
I've tried placing it next to package name, but it didn't work.
